# MvcSitemapProvider throwing Overflow exception when using currentNode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using MvcSitemapProvider for my ASP MVC 5 project.

I've implemented a custom Authorize to check if roles from sitemap are equal to users roles.

This is what it looks like:

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool authorize = false;

        var roles = SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode.Roles;
        foreach (var role in roles)
            if (System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(role))
                authorize = true;

        return authorize;
    }
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

My issue is that when using `SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode.Roles` it throws a `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll` and I have no clue why. The objects are filled, nothing is null.

Why does this happen? Right now I'm clueless about how to get this to work as a simple currentNode doesn't work...

Comment: When you're debugging does it get to the for each loop or is the exception thrown before that?

Comment: It's thrown at method currentNode which is a mvcsitemapprovider method. That's why I'm clueless what to do as I can't affect it nor know why it is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation of `AuthorizeAttribute` is all you need to interact with `MvcSiteMapProvider`. `AuthorizeAttribute` already supports roles.

```
// Only users in the "Manager" role have access to all actions on this controller
[Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Manage()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The only thing you need to do is enable security trimming. See the [security trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming#aspnet-mvc-security-primer) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. I know I could use it like you advise but I'd like it to be dependent on the sitemap because I'd want to change it at runtime. Controllers are compiled and not able to change... Thats why I want to get the sitemap roles at current node and check if user has those roles. 

Is there any other way?

Comment: You cannot use the roles collection for this purpose. The SiteMap is cached and shared for all users and it is not possible to change roles dynamically at runtime. You should look for another way to define this dynamic behavior, but you are using the right approach by subclassing AuthorizeAttribute so it only has to be defined in one place. Have a look at MVC 5 claims.

Answer (score 1):

I think the call to current node is generating another request for the page which will again invoke your authorization filter. In other words, this code is creating an infinite loop of calls to itself none of which ever return which is why the call stack is overflowing.

I would store the roles you want to check for in another way.

Comment: Most likely! I guess I'll have to use acl module and skip custom attribute.